# Reading a black-and-white image as 0's and 1's

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I read a black-and-white image file as ones and zeros?  I'm using VC++6, OpenCv, and the FANN (Faster Artificial Neural Network) Library.

Comment: You refer to "the file" as if we know what the hell you're talking about.  Like it was a conversation we had by the water cooler 5 minutes ago.

Comment: I mean that's Read image (white & black) as a file  of (0 and 1)
 I need to store the image after read as a file of (0 and 1

Comment: Do you need to store:  column-wise, or row-wise?  Does the data need to be padded to nearest 8-bit, 16-bit, 24-bit or 32-bit quantity?  Which order are the bits written, LSB or MSB first?  Is the image a mirror, platform dependent, from memory?  Are the pixel values 0 for black or white?  Is there a scale, e.g. 0 to 255 for grayscale?  Soooooo many questions, so little time.

Comment: Where is the orignal, source image coming from, e.g. a file, a camera, graphics chip, etc?  What is the format of the image in the file?  How many bits per pixel?  How many pixels per row?  Is the data interlaced, e.g. even scan lines followed by all odd scans?  Does the file contain any compression such as Run Length Encoding or Huffman?

Answer (score 2):

The pixel data in an image file is represented in a format.  There are may different methods for organizing pixel data in a file:  TIFF, JPEG, GIF, PNG, BMP, etc., just to name a few.  Need more information about your file before detailed help can be given.

All data in a file is made of ones and zeros, just the nature of the computer world.  Perhaps if you indicate what you are doing with the image data, more information can be presented.

See the following:

1. Wikipedia page on image formats.
2. std::ifstream::open, binary mode.
3. std::ifstream::read
4. std::vector to hold
   the data.
5. Search Stack Overflow for the keywords "read binary file".

Answer (score 1):

Open the file.  Read each pixel's color value, and interpret a white pixel as a `1` and a black pixel as a `0`.

If you expect me to write this program for you, I bill out at $250 US per hour.

Comment: Much cheaper compared to competitors :P

Comment: Why go through the trouble of reading these 'pixels', as you call them? Just open the file in binary mode and start cranking out the 1's and 0's! This high efficiency solution will only cost $500 - flat rate!